# What's the difference between an Epi Junior and a Junior Special?

Tags: guitar

I was recently gifted a very gently used Epiphone Junior, and was wondering  what the difference is between that and a Junior Special.  Just curious, is all.

Answer (score 1):

I looked through my old Epiphone catalogue and checked the web site and I didn't find any model of the Junior other than the standard. The Les Paul Special was a popular model, so people selling the Junior may mistakenly be adding the word Special to the description, or calling it the Junior Special to indicate what model it is patterned after.

If there is a version that you have found that includes the word "special" on the head stock instead of just "Junior Model", it is possible that it is from a short run of the model. Occasionally a manufacturer will put out a short run that is for specific promotional events, or to introduce a special or new component such as a different Humbucker, electronics or finish.